# unwanted space in tr wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

wkhtmltopdf version(s) affected: wkhtmltox-0.12.5-1.msvc2015-win64

Getting unwanted space in TR
check attached snapshot for clarification.

Issue appears when we use div inside td.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In the `div` you are using inside `td` add `display: inline-block` to see if it solves the problem.